# large packages extremely slow to remove or update

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Im using visual studio 2012 (also 2013). and TFS integration using the free online tfs repository.

I have angularjs installed which has 57 files in the route of the scripts folder and 245 localisation versions in the subfolder `i18n`. If i for example have angular 1.2rc3 installed and i upgrade to v1.2 (both via the package console or via the GUI). It causes visual studio to be unusable for 30+ minutes. This machine has sufficient free resources and a fast connection to the internet.

This can be replicated by removing the package also.  Is behaviour a known issue?  Incidentally installing angularjs 1.2 to a new solution took a "normal" amount of time i.e. around 20 seconds.

Comment: same issue with angular here. upgrading from 1.07 to 1.2 takes forever.

Comment: yes @ZarShardan its still an issue with nuget 2.8

Comment: Same issue both Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 Preview.
Just updating from 1.3.2 to 1.3.3.
Also using TFS Online.

Answer (score 2):

I use several Visual Studio 2013- 2015 Preview and I have the same problem like some of my friends, if you search on your favorite search engine you will find others also complaining about this issue, I use TFS online on top of this and sometimes updates took not minutes, hours packages like angularjs + JqueryUI packages
for VS 2015 this problem kinda solved, now we use bower instead nuget for client packages 
and for VS 2013 I started using smaller packages instead of full packages like I start using AngularJS Core(just 4 files) > https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngularJS.Core
instead

(I Know this may not the answer you are looking for but I don't have 50rep to make this is  a Comment and this issue took my hours several time)